# How to return next line in text file in python

Tags: python

```
def openFood():
    with open("FoodList.txt")  as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    if 'Food' in line:
                        print(f.next())
openFood()
```

I want it where when it sees a certain header like 'Food' It will print the line below it. I cant seem to make it work. The text file will be like

```
Food
Apple
Cal 120
Protein 12
Fat 13 
Carb 23
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `f.next()`? file object provides an iterator, not an iterable. Calling `readlines()` exhausts the iterator, so f.next() would never really give you anything.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the index.

```
def openFood():
    with open("FoodList.txt")  as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)-1):
            if 'Food' in lines[i]:
                print(lines[i+1])
openFood()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
def openFood():
    with open("FoodList.txt")  as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    for ind, line in enumerate(lines):
        if 'Food' in line:
            try:
                print(lines[ind + 1])
            except:
                print('No line after "Food"')
openFood()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `readlines()` returns a list of the lines in the file that you can iterate over, you can simply access the subsequent line via its index:

```
l = len(lines)-1
for i in range(l):
    if 'Food' in lines[i]:
        print(lines[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `readlines()` returns list object, you can convert it to an iterator and then use `next` function:

```
def openFood():
    with open("FoodList.txt") as f:
        lines = iter(f.readlines())
        for line in lines:
            if 'Food' in line:
                print(next(lines))
openFood()
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file one line at a time can be beneficial if the file is very large. This code will not load the full file into memory, but only one line at a time:

```
def openFood():
    with open("FoodList.txt") as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            if 'Food' in line:
                print(f.readline())
            line = f.readline()

openFood()
```

Result:

```
Apple
```

**Note**: This method will be a lot slower for smaller files, than reading the contents into memory using the `readlines()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` reads all the lines in a file and returns a list. You could either read and iterate one line at a time (using `readline()`), or read all the lines and use the list for iteration (using `readlines()`).

Apart from the ways mentioned, you could also use a `bool` like below (I've used `readlines()` here):

```py
def openFood():
    with open("FoodList.txt")  as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        trigger = "Food"
        triggerfound = False

        for line in lines:
            if triggerfound:
                print(line)
                triggerfound = False

            if trigger in line:
                triggerfound = True

openFood()
```